# Converting dict values to integers when not all values are integers python

Tags: python, integer, key-value-coding

I have this code that gives me lists with keys:values. Firstly i'm accessing the `'symbol'` key to filter everything but the lists which 'symbol' values end with ***BTC. Secondly I'm trying to access the `'quoteVolume'` key and filter out all lists that have a value below e.g `100`. The problem arises here since the list values are both strings and numbers and within the strings are both letters and numbers. And the value of `'quoteVolume'` is a string.

Code:

```
import requests

#gets list with key and value data for all ticker pairs
data = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr')
dataJson = data.json()

#takes value from key 'symbol', can now search for certain symbols
dataDictionary = {d['symbol'] : d for d in dataJson}

#filters out everything but pairs that end with ***BTC
BTC_markets = dict(filter(lambda pair: pair[0][-3:] == 'BTC', dataDictionary.items()))

#filters lists with < 100 quoteVolume
high_volume_BTC_markets =  dict(filter(market_filter(['quoteVolume']),BTC_markets.items()))

print('Active high volume BTC Markets: ')
pprint(high_volume_BTC_markets)
```

The lists are about 100x and 1 looks like this

BTC_markets output:

```
 'STMXBTC': {'askPrice': '0.00000023',
             'askQty': '58640610.00000000',
             'bidPrice': '0.00000022',
             'bidQty': '130870153.00000000',
             'closeTime': 1594290726823,
             'count': 2842,
             'firstId': 66352,
             'highPrice': '0.00000024',
             'lastId': 69193,
             'lastPrice': '0.00000022',
             'lastQty': '2109909.00000000',
             'lowPrice': '0.00000022',
             'openPrice': '0.00000022',
             'openTime': 1594204326823,
             'prevClosePrice': '0.00000022',
             'priceChange': '0.00000000',
             'priceChangePercent': '0.000',
             'quoteVolume': '162.70619311',
             'symbol': 'STMXBTC',
             'volume': '713198749.00000000',
             'weightedAvgPrice': '0.00000023'},
```

So how can I transform all the lists `quoteVolume`value from `str` to `ìnt` without getting an error because of not all strings can be turned into numbers?

I'm very new to this and have been searching for a good couple of days before posting, I've tried different methods which i've encountered but havent found anything that works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try `float()` or `decimal.Decimal()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convert_to_int(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            convert_to_int(v)
        else:
            try:
                d[k] = int(float(v)) # or just float(v) for floating point conversion:
            except Exception:
                pass # ignore conversion errors and keep original value

convert_to_int(BTC_markets)
print(BTC_markets)
```

Now to get a `list` of all `quoteVolume` values in the topmost dictionaries:

```
quoteVolumes = [(k, BTC_markets[k]['quoteVolume']) for k in BTC_markets]
filtered_quoteVolumes = filter(lambda item: item[1] >= 100, quoteVolumes)
new_dict = dict(filtered_quoteVolumes)
```

Comment: Hey man! And thanks for replying! I tried this, replacing d with BTC_markets, but nothing changed, should i replace something more to get it working?

Comment: Awesome! it works but now its only for the 'STMXBTC' pair, the goal is to have it done on all pairs. I tried removing the square brackets but then the numbers became strings again. Sorry if I'm missing some obvious stuff here

Comment: See updated answer. This will convert all nested dictionaries.

Comment: Yess it does! but when trying to reach those integers with ```res = [ sub['quoteVolume'] for sub in BTC_markets ]``` it returns error that string indicies must be integers?

Comment: It gives the quoteVolume but now in a random order so i have no idea which quoteVolume belongs to which symbol. I try to write a filter() function instead, but i dont know how/where in the lambda to specify that its the quoteVolume value i want to exceed 100 ```volume_filter = dict(filter(lambda pair: pair > 100, BTC_markets.items()))```

Comment: I've edited it one more time to give you a list of tuples such as ('STMXBTC', 162). You can do your own filtering on this. You can create a new dictionary from these tuples before or after filtering.

Comment: Awesome man, much appreciated! Once this bot makes me a fortune im sending you some BTC :D

Answer (score 0):

Well `quoteVolume` looks like `'162.70619311'` which is a string containing a float so you can't directly use `int()`, you need to first use `float()` like so:

```
value = int(float(your_quote_volume))
```

Doing that you are flooring it so it becomes `162`. If you need to keep the decimal then don't do the `int()`.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer my man! Trying to figure how to implement this in the code, as said, I'm quite new to this. What is it that I'm using float() on?